# How to select only one year data from this week in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table like following

```
year  month isoweek day
・
・
2020  12     49  2021/12/5
・
・ 
2020  12　   50  2021/12/7
・
・
2021  12     51  2021/12/20 
2021  12     51  2021/12/21
```

I'd like to select only one year in `isoweek`
in this example, today is `2021/12/20` and its isoweek in this table is `51`
I'd like to get `2020` isoweek `52` to `2021` isoweek `51`.
Are there any way to achieve this?

```
year  month isoweek day
2020  12　   52  2020/12/21 
・
・
2021  12     51  2021/12/20 
2021  12     51  2021/12/21
```

I tried following query, but it still cant extract one year range.

```
select *
from table
where day <= current_date
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select      t.*
from        tbl                           t
cross join  (
              select  yr,
                      isoweek
              from    tbl
              where   dt = trunc(sysdate)
            )                             x
where       (t.yr = x.yr - 1 and t.isoweek > x.isoweek)
         or (t.yr = x.yr     and t.isoweek <= x.isoweek);
```

I've changed some column and table names for purposes of avoiding reserved words in a fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98de6d/1/0

The year of data in this query is based on the current date, as that is what you alluded to being desired. If a different date were desired, replace `trunc(sysdate)` with a given date.